# python sequence assignment error in multi-line

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I'm new to Python, when I wrote the code as the book did, IDLE gives me the error

```
Token Error:EOF in multi-line statement
```

I suppose this error maybe happened because of the "months" sequence. 
How can I fix it?

I use Python 2.7.9

```
months = [
'January',
'February',
'March',
'April',
'May',
'June',
'July',
'August',
'September',
'October',
'November',
'December'
]

endings = ['st','nd','rd']+17*['th']\
     +['st','nd','rd']+7*['th']\
     +['st']

year=raw_input('Year:')
month=raw_input('Month:')
day=raw_input('Day:')

month_number=int(month)
day_number=int(day)

month_name=months[month_number-1]
day_name=day+endings[day_number-1]
print month_name+' '+day_name+','+year
```

**I executed the 'wrong' .py file again,this time the IDLE didn't show me error,but I didn't change any codes in this file,how could it be possible,I'm confused now...**

Comment: Could you please tell us the line number where the error occurs?

Comment: There's no problem on my computer! (Python 2.7.8)

Comment: Your code works for me. :P

Comment: the last time i saw the error occured,it marked the last line(the 'print ...' line)